# SharePoint Pivot Upload

Tags: sharepoint

Every morning at 2:00am (or when ever all the pivots finish building) I run a vb.net program to upload all the pivots to a specified shared documents folder inside of SharePoint.  Sunday through Friday the script runs perfectly but on Saturday morning it fails to connect via webdav.

"The specified network name is no longer available"

This is strange because we even put a 30 second delay in there if it receives such an error to give the site time to wake up if that is the case. There is nothing strange showing up in the event viewer on the Pivot Server or on the SharePoint server.

I have a few other programs/scripts running during the day that work flawlessly every single day.

- PowerShell script to upload all users from Active Directory into 410 various groups
- PowerShell script to set the permissions of the Pivot folders so only the right people see their pivots (This runs at 3:00am and works fine)
- And a few others

I can't seem to track down this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some powershell "sharepoint warmup" scripts to be found on the interwebs, that basically loop through all site collections and makes a request, firing up all web apps, maybe you could give that a try, have it run say every day at 6 in the morning?

Comment: Thank you!  I have been looking for the warm up script for some time.  I kept searching for "wakup script" for the last 2 weeks.

I'll mark this question as answered once I know this works

Comment: no problem, the warmup thing is a known "feature" of sharepoint, hope things are different in 2010...

Comment: It turns out that it is not sharepoint that is screwing up but rather the program made to upload or something like that.  I will keep the script around anyways :).  Thank you!

Comment: My post above was not the culprit either.  There was a scheduled job every Saturday at 2am to reboot the server where the Pivots are located.  Problem solved by not rebooting then :)

Comment: cool you updated your post, and that you found the answer. SharePoint is (as you now know :-D) a bitch when it comes down to tracking down the source of a problem...... But I still love developing for it :-D.